# Enum stubs in Interfaces?

Tags: c#

I've got an enum defined in one of my Enum.cs classes inside this project where these interfaces lie.

I've got an Interface called IPhoto and in it I need to put a property called FileType because other methods in this service expect it so I want any class implementing IPhoto to have this defined so they know about it.

Does this seem out of place or you just wouldn't do such a thing?  How would I define this then?

I mean I can't just do this:

```
MyEnum FileType;
```

The thing is all files have a type.  And in my concrete classes I signal that using an Enum (so jpeg, etc.).  So any class implementing this needs to definitely have a FileType property somehow.

Comment: How about `MyEnum FileType { get; set; }`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add a property to an interface.  See the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/64syzecx%28VS.80%29.aspx).

```
public interface ISampleInterface 
{    
    MyEnum FileType
    {
        get;
    }
}
```

Now all implementations of the interface have to define a getter for that property.

Answer (score 2):

I can't see any reason not to do it if it's part of the interface your objects need to conform to, if you want to add a read-only property to an interface you just do it like so:

```
public interface IPhoto
{
    MyEnum FileType
    {
        get;
    }
}
```

Read-write would be:

```
public interface IPhoto
{
    MyEnum FileType
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok what if the enum is in a different assembly and your interfaces need to use it but you can't add that assembly to your project because it'd create a circular reference.  I mean I don't want to have two completely different places and dup for this enum (varying by a namespace)

Comment: The way to typically deal with circular refs is to extract the common classes out into another assembly and then have the two other assemblies depend on that common one.

Comment: yea I know.  I'm saying though you want to share an enum between 2 abstractions.  Yea could create a thrid assembly such as "Utilities" but that's prob the only way as you're right.  Problem with my boss is he refuses to abstract out more layers...and if I don't comply I get fired.  wtf

Answer (score 0):

When all your possible filetypes are previously known you can use an enum. And of course you can just add a property to your interface for exactly that enum type.

If the services can define their own filetypes you will have to use a class (that can then be subclassed).

Comment: well most are all known, the majority at least that we're gonna be using.

Comment: Well *most* is not enough. An enumeration is basically a list of constants. *IF* even a single one of your services needs to define a filetype on its own you can't use an enum.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
public enum MyEnum { one, two, three }
public interface Bar { MyEnum Whatever { get; set; } }
```

Comment: It's the same as the other ones above just with the linebreaks missing ;)